# Superscript cents in an attributed string

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to get my label to look like so:

[image]

But using attributed string, I managed to get this result:

[image]

My code:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",ask];

NSMutableAttributedString *buyString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

[buyString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                  value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]
                  range:NSMakeRange(2, buyString.length - 2)];

self.labelBuy.attributedText = buyString;
```

As you see, the numbers after the dot, stay below, and I would like to pop them to the top as the first example.
Is there any way to set attributed string frame?

Comment: My guess is that you have to use two `UILabel`s (and hence two attributed strings) instead of one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `NSBaselineOffsetAttributedName`.

From the doc:

> `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` 
>   The value of this attribute is an
>   `NSNumber` object containing a floating point value indicating the
>   character’s offset from the baseline, in points. The default value is
>   0. 
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

From your example:

```
[buyString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
                  value:@(10.0)
                  range:NSMakeRange(2, buyString.length - 2)];
```

You may have to change the value to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not actually use superscript? You must first #import "CoreText/CoreText.h"

```
    [buyString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName 
                      value:@1 
                      range:NSMakeRange(2, buyString.length - 2)];
```

Comment: Seems to place the cents too high, with bottom of cents aligned to top of the whole number value.