# iOS how to draw text in a UILabel using a non standard alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-text

I want to put numbers in a label with alignment like in the image. None of the label's alignment modes could help me.

The decimal digits should be above the centre line and between the top margin. The other digits should be aligned in a regular fashion. 
I don't even know what the "professional" name is for a thing like this or any sort of API that can help.

Can somebody point me in the direction or have an example snippet?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think you can do that using attributed text

Comment: Looking into it but don't see any thing ...

Comment: What you are looking for is called superscript (upper index) or subscript (below index)

Comment: You could also made it with constraints (if you have separated dollars and cents in two different labels)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This seems to do the trick

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367017/superscript-cents-in-an-attributed-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code. I have done it by using `NSMutableAttributedString`.

```
NSString *str = @"$899.00";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [NSMutableAttributedString new];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrSuperScript = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
[attrSuperScript addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"-1" range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length] - 3)];
[attrSuperScript addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:28] range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
[attrSuperScript addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15] range:NSMakeRange([str length] - 3, 3)];

[attrString appendAttributedString:attrSuperScript];
[attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 50)];
[label setAttributedText:attrString];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

A sample screen shot of output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can achieve it is using the NSSuperscriptAttribute attribute of NSAttributed string...

If you need something fancier, i believe the only options are using 2 labels, or custom drawing code / core text

Comment: I don't think that `NSSuperscriptAttribute` is available now. Please check again.

Comment: You're right, use `(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName`, you need to import CoreText first