# -[__NSCFString _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:timeString];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.txtFieldForEndTime.font.familyName size:self.txtFieldForEndTime.font.pointSize / 2];

    NSDictionary *attrs = @{
                            NSFontAttributeName:font,
                            (__bridge NSString *)  kCTSuperscriptAttributeName:[string substringFromIndex:string.length - 2]
                            };
    [attString setAttributes:attrs range:[string rangeOfString:@"PM"]];
```

The above code is trying to super script the last two AM / PM characters.

But the app is crashing by stating -[__NSCFString _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this code. If you have working code which superscripts a part of NSString please let me know.

Comment: `self.txtFieldForEndTime.font.familyName` => `self.txtFieldForEndTime.font.fontName`? That could be one issue. The other one, is the value of `attrs` for key `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName`. It's expecting a `NSNumber`, not a `NSString`

Comment: Its the problem with `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName`. The font is working correctly. Then how would I display any character as superscripted?

Comment: `(__bridge NSString *)  kCTSuperscriptAttributeName:[string substringFromIndex:string.length - 2]` to `(__bridge NSString *)  kCTSuperscriptAttributeName:@(1)` or `(__bridge NSString *)  kCTSuperscriptAttributeName:@(-1)` as it's stated in the doc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Superscript cents in an attributed string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367017/superscript-cents-in-an-attributed-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fake superscript by reducing the point size of the font, and use the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute to move the text up or down the baseline.