# Display fraction number in UILabel superscript in an attributed string

Tags: ios, iphone, superscript

I'm trying to get my label to look like:

[image: I want to superscript Last Three Digit Look Like]

I want to superscript and subscript Look Like in Image.
Is this possible to do with NSAttributedString, or is there an alternative/easier way to make superscript?

Thanks In Advance..

Comment: With `NSBaselineOffsetAttributedName ` it's possible for the subscript, `NSFontAttributeName` the the font size/bold font.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Superscript cents in an attributed string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367017/superscript-cents-in-an-attributed-string)