# cos⁻¹ button title in Swift

Tags: swift, string, uibutton, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have an calculator app, and current the cos⁻¹ button looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

What is the easiest way of accomplishing this? Is there any way of doing this without messing with `NSAttributedString`? Are there any special characters that I can use?

Comment: Unless you have a UTF-8 way of superscripting characters (I'm fairly sure you don't) then I guess you have to "mess around with `NSAttributedString`. One other thing - you *could* work with an image, but I'd think that is "messier".

Comment: @dfd, You don't need to use attributes. There are unicode characters for superscripted number strings.

Comment: For NSAttributedString: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367017/superscript-cents-in-an-attributed-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly doable. There are unicode characters for superscripted digits and the "-" sign. Just paste the string `cos⁻¹` into your button title, label, or other view with text content. (You can even copy/paste from this answer)

I got the characters from this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts